# Seekbar shared preferences

Tags: android

I am using a viewpager(with images) and in viewpager i have set the shared preferences like when the user launch the activity he can see the last seen page when he exit the activity...

the sharedreferences of viewpager is working fine for me . i am using the seekbar to slide the images in viewpager but  how can i use the same sharedpreferences
in the seekbar to update the postion of the seekbar to the last seen page or spot.
or how can i automatically update the progress of seekbar if user slider the images on viewpager. i am new in the field of the android and this is my first post.. Please someone help me out..

my code:

```
public static ViewPager viewPager;
Customswipeadapter adapter;
public  static int  a;
public static int idName;
private SeekBar seekBar;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
    adapter = new Customswipeadapter(this);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new RotateDownTransformer());
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(images_resources.length);
    a = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

    ////SHARED PREFERENCES///
    android.content.SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("page_store", MODE_PRIVATE);
    idName = prefs.getInt("Page_number", 0); //0 is the default value.
    Toast.makeText(this, " Name"+idName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (idName != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(idName);
        //Toast.makeText(viewpager.this,"Page no:"+ idName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

   //Seekbar start


    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                int progress = 0;
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                              int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                   progress = images_resources.length-progresValue;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(progress);

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // Do something here,
                    //if you want to do anything at the start of
                    // touching the seekbar
                    progress = seekBar.getProgress();

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // Display the value in textview
                    //textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

                }
            });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu;
    //this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}  ///Seekbar End


    //BACK PRESS METHOD
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    a = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("page_store", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("Page_number", a);
    //Toast.makeText(this, " "+a , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    editor.commit();
    finish();
}
//END OF SHARED PREFERENCES
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can add a addOnPageChangeListener to your viewPager and implements his methods an in the onPageSelected you can set the progress of the seekbar in %.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            seekbar.setProgress((position * 100)/viewPager.getChildCount());

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```